# How to resize the following picture in LaTeX using pstricks?

Tags: pstricks

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}

%\bpsp(3,2.5)
%\psgrid[subgriddiv=1,griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt](-2,0)(8,3)
\vspace{3cm}
\rput(5.7,0.25){
\psline(0,1)(2,1)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](2,1)(3,1)
\psline(3,1)(4,1)
\psdot(0,1)
\psdot(1,1)
\psdot(2,1)
\psdot(3,1)
\psdot(4,1)
\pscurve[linestyle=dotted](5.3,1.59)(5.45,1.3)(5.4,1.04)
\pscurve[linestyle=dotted](5.3,.45)(5.45,.71)(5.4,.98)
\psline(4,1)(5,0)
\psline(4,1)(5,2)
\psline(5.4,1)(4,1)
\psline(-1,2)(0,1)(-1,0)
\psdot(-1,2)
\psdot(-1,0)
\psdot(5.4,1)
\psline(5.3,.4)(4,1)(5.3,1.6)
\psline(-1.3,1.5)(0,1)(-1.3,.5)
\psdot(-1.3,1.5)
\psdot(-1.3,.5)
\pscurve[linestyle=dotted](-1.1,2)(-1.5,1)(-1.1,0)
\psdot(5.3,1.6)
\psdot(5.3,.4)
\psdot(5,0)
\psdot(5,2)
\rput(0.1,.8){$u_0$}
\rput(1,.8){$u_1$}
\rput(2,.8){$u_2$}
\rput(3.8,.8){$u_{k-s-t}$}
\rput[l](-3.5,1){$s$ vertices $\Bigg\{$}
\rput[l](5.6,1){$\Bigg\} t$ vertices}
}
%epsp
\caption{The graph $\mathcal{P}(k,s,t)$}\label{pkst}

\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

I am trying to scale the size of the figure. How we can do that?

Comment: Just a question: are the series of dots at both ends supposed to be on a circle?

Comment: You might need `\psscalebox`.

Answer (score 3):

No need for scaling. Just use the correct image size for `pspicture`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,0)(7.5,2)
  \psline{*-*}(0,1)(2,1)\psdot(1,1)
  \psline[linestyle=dashed]{-*}(2,1)(3,1)
  \psline{-*}(3,1)(4,1)
  \psarc[linestyle=dotted](0,1){1.5}{135}{225}
  \psarc[linestyle=dotted](4,1){1.5}{-45}{45}
  \rput(0,1){\psforeach{\iA}{135,157.5,205.5,225}{\psline{-*}(1.5;\iA)}}
  \rput(4,1){\psforeach{\iA}{-45,-22.5,0,22.5,45}{\psline{-*}(1.5;\iA)}}
  \uput{10pt}[-90](0,1){$u_0$}
  \uput{10pt}[-90](1,1){$u_1$}
  \uput{10pt}[-90](2,1){$u_2$}
  \uput*{10pt}[-90](4,1){$u_{k-s-t}$}
  \rput[r](-1.5,1){$s$ vertices $\Bigg\{$}
  \rput[l](5.6,1){$\Bigg\} t$ vertices}
\end{pspicture}
\caption{The graph $\mathcal{P}(k,s,t)$}\label{pkst}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for \psforeach...

Answer (score 1):

You can resize a pspicture, without resizing the text – which leads to inconsistent font sizes, using `\psset{unit=...}` at the beginning (the default unit is 1cm; I chose here `unit=0.8cm`). Here is an example. I took the opportunity to simplify your code, with a systematic use of psnodes, and the adjunction of the `pst-eucl` package/

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,, oneside]{article}

    \usepackage{pst-all, pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \psset{unit=0.8cm}
    \centering
    \begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-1.3)(7.5,1.3)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={u_0,u_1,u_2,none, u_{k-s-t},none}, PosAngle=-90](0,0){U0}(1,0){U1}(2,0){U2}(3,0){U3}(4,0){U4}(5.4,0){B0}
    \psline(U0)(U2)\psline[linestyle=dashed, dash=3pt 2pt](U2)(U3)\psline(U3)(B0)
    \foreach \ang/\i in {-50/1,-30/2,30/3,50/4}{\dotnode[PointName=none](-1.4;\ang){A\i}\AtoB(A\i)(U4){B\i} \psline(A\i)\psline[arrows=-*](U4)(B\i)}
    \pstArcOAB[linestyle=dotted]{U0}{A1}{A4}
    \pstArcOAB[linestyle=dotted]{U4}{B2}{B3}
    \pnodes[-0.8em, 0](A2){C2}(A3){C3}
    \pnodes[0.8em, 0](B2){D2}(B3){D3}
    \psset{braceWidth=1pt, braceWidthInner=3pt, braceWidthOuter=3pt}
    \psbrace[ref=rC, nodesepA=-2pt](C2)(C3){$s$ vertices}
    \psbrace[ref=lC, nodesepA= 2pt](D2)(D3){$t$ vertices}
    \end{pspicture}
    \caption{The graph $\mathcal{P}(k,s,t)$}\label{pkst}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]